# Mark Seams on Edges of Camera View

Tags: python, mesh, bmesh

I am trying to write a script to mark a seam on an object around the vertices of the object that are in the field of view of the camera.  Unfortunately, some of my `bpy.ops.mesh` calls don't seem to be occurring correctly, and I haven't been able to figure out why.

- `bpy.ops.mesh.region_to_loop()` - is deselecting all vertices
- `bpy.ops.mesh.mark_seam(clear=False)` - is not marking any seams, even when `region_to_loop` is commented out and vertices are selected

Please see the relevant code below:

```
def find_edges(self, mapping_target, projector):
    mesh=bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.object.data)
    vert_list = self.find_intersecting_verts(projector, mapping_target, mesh, True)

    #Select all vertices on the edge
    bpy.ops.mesh.region_to_loop()
    #Mark the edges for the projector
    bpy.ops.mesh.mark_seam(clear=False)

#Compute the vertices of a mesh which are covered
#by a projector's field of view.  This does not perform clipping calculations
#return a list of vertices that were intersected
#Note: Tested & Functioning Correctly
#@param - projector: the camera object being mapped
#@param - target: The target mesh being mapped
#@param - select_results: True to select the resulting vertices, in this case target should be in edit mode prior to running
def find_intersecting_verts(self, projector, target, target_mesh, select_results):

    return_list = []
    mesh=target_mesh

    print("Find Intersecting Vertices:")

    if select_results == True:
        v_list = mesh.verts
    else:
        v_list = target.data.vertices

    #For each vertex in the target, we need to figure out if v falls within the view of the projector
    for v in v_list:

        print("Testing vertex <%s, %s, %s>" % (v.co[0], v.co[1], v.co[2]))

        #Scene
        scene = bpy.context.scene

        #Active Object: Camera (Projector)
        obj = projector.object

        #Point being compared
        co = v.co

        v_proj_n = bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view(scene, obj, co)
        v_p = mathutils.Vector((v_proj_n[0], v_proj_n[1]))

        a = mathutils.Vector((0.0, 0.0))
        b = mathutils.Vector((1.0, 0.0))
        c = mathutils.Vector((1.0, 1.0))

        #Run the comparison on the rectangle vs the point
        #Algorithm from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752725/finding-whether-a-point-lies-inside-a-rectangle-or-not

        if 0 <= (b-a).dot(v_p - a) <= (b-a).dot(b-a) and\
            0 <= (c-b).dot(v_p - b) <= (c-b).dot(c-b) and v_proj_n[2] >= 0.0:

            return_list.append(v.co)
            print(v.co)

            #Select the vertex
            if select_results == True:
                v.select = True

    if select_results == True:
        # trigger viewport update
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.context.scene.objects.active

    return return_list
```

Comment: If this helps, this is in reference to a full project on GitHub which can be found [here](https://github.com/AO-StreetArt/BlenderMap)